# Extract Meta Keywords in python?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I wrote a code for keywords extraction from websites. Some websites have keywords information but my program returns empty list. how can we fix that can u please some suggestion. Websites is  in code. In these 3 url i get keyword only from one website:

#### code

```
data=['http://www.supermap.com','http://www.itc.com','http://www.astro.com']

for url in data:

     print(str(i)+" : "+url)

     i=i+1

     try:

         html=requests.get(url, timeout=60)

         soup3 = BeautifulSoup(html.text,"html.parser")

         meta = soup3.findAll(attrs={"name":'description'})

         meta1= soup3.findAll(attrs={"name":'keywords'})

         t=[]

         t1=[]

         for link in meta:

              a=link.get("content")

              t.append(a)

         for link in meta1:

              a=link.get("content")

              t1.append(a)

         meta=str(t)

         meta1=str(t1)

         cur.execute("insert into key_meta(url,descript,keywords)values(?, ?, ?)", (url, meta, meta1)) 

         con.commit()
```

Answer (score 4):

The code below collects the required data. It works for 2/3 of the urls.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URLS = ['http://www.astro.com', 'http://www.supermap.com', 'http://www.itc.com']
ATTRIBUTES = ['description', 'keywords', 'Description', 'Keywords']

collected_data = []

for url in URLS:
    entry = {'url': url}
    try:
        r = requests.get(url)
    except Exception as e:
        print('Could not load page {}. Reason: {}'.format(url, str(e)))
        continue
    if r.status_code == 200:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
        meta_list = soup.find_all("meta")
        for meta in meta_list:
            if 'name' in meta.attrs:
                name = meta.attrs['name']
                if name in ATTRIBUTES:
                    entry[name.lower()] = meta.attrs['content']
        if len(entry) == 3:
            collected_data.append(entry)
        else:
            print('Could not find all required attributes for URL {}'.format(url))
    else:
        print('Could not load page {}.Reason: {}'.format(url, r.status_code))
print('Collected meta attributes (TODO - push to DB):')
for entry in collected_data:
    print(entry)
```

Output

```
Could not find all required attributes for URL http://www.itc.com
Collected meta attributes (TODO - push to DB):
{'url': 'http://www.astro.com', u'keywords': u'Astrodienst, horoscope, horoscopes, horoscope 2013, free horoscopes, daily horoscope, astrology, love, aries, taurus, gemini, cancer, leo, virgo, libra, scorpio, sagittarius, capricorn, aquarius, pisces, zodiac, starsigns, forecast, yearly horoscope, liz greene, robert hand, sunsign, birth chart', u'description': u"Free Astrology and Horoscopes from Astrodienst! Get your free horoscope - and much more! Astrodienst provides the world's best astrology site for free horoscopes, professional astrological reports and information about astrology."}
{'url': 'http://www.supermap.com', u'keywords': u'\xb5\xd8\xc0\xed\xd0\xc5\xcf\xa2,GIS,\xb5\xd8\xc0\xed\xd0\xc5\xcf\xa2\xcf\xb5\xcd\xb3,\xd4\xc6GIS,\xc8\xfd\xce\xacGIS,\xd2\xc6\xb6\xafGIS,\xbf\xd5\xbc\xe4\xb4\xf3\xca\xfd\xbe\xdd,GIS\xbd\xe2\xbe\xf6\xb7\xbd\xb0\xb8,GIS\xb0\xb8\xc0\xfd', u'description': u'\xb1\xb1\xbe\xa9\xb3\xac\xcd\xbc\xc8\xed\xbc\xfe\xd6\xf7\xd2\xaa\xb4\xd3\xca\xc2\xb5\xd8\xc0\xed\xd0\xc5\xcf\xa2\xcf\xb5\xcd\xb3 (GIS)\xbb\xf9\xb4\xa1\xc8\xed\xbc\xfe\xc6\xbd\xcc\xa8\xd1\xd0\xbe\xbf\xa1\xa2\xbf\xaa\xb7\xa2\xba\xcd\xcf\xfa\xca\xdb\xa3\xac\xce\xaa\xd5\xfe\xb8\xae\xba\xcd\xc6\xf3\xd2\xb5\xcc\xe1\xb9\xa9\xb5\xd8\xc0\xed\xbf\xd5\xbc\xe4\xd0\xc5\xcf\xa2\xbc\xbc\xca\xf5\xb5\xc4\xd7\xc9\xd1\xaf\xb7\xfe\xce\xf1\xa1\xa3SuperMap GIS\xcf\xb5\xc1\xd0\xc8\xed\xbc\xfe\xd6\xf7\xd2\xaa\xb0\xfc\xc0\xa8\xd4\xc6GIS\xc6\xbd\xcc\xa8\xc8\xed\xbc\xfe\xa1\xa2\xd7\xe9\xbc\xfeGIS\xbf\xaa\xb7\xa2\xc6\xbd\xcc\xa8\xa1\xa2\xd2\xc6\xb6\xafGIS\xbf\xaa\xb7\xa2\xc6\xbd\xcc\xa8\xa1\xa2\xd7\xc0\xc3\xe6GIS\xc6\xbd\xcc\xa8\xa1\xa2\xcd\xf8\xc2\xe7\xbf\xcd\xbb\xa7\xb6\xcbGIS\xbf\xaa\xb7\xa2\xc6\xbd\xcc\xa8\xd2\xd4\xbc\xb0\xcf\xe0\xb9\xd8\xb5\xc4\xbf\xd5\xbc\xe4\xca\xfd\xbe\xdd\xc9\xfa\xb2\xfa\xa1\xa2\xbc\xd3\xb9\xa4\xba\xcd\xb9\xdc\xc0\xed\xb9\xa4\xbe\xdf\xa1\xa3\xbe\xad\xb9\xfd\xb6\xfe\xca\xae\xc4\xea\xb7\xa2\xd5\xb9\xa3\xacSuperMap GIS\xd2\xd1\xbe\xad\xb3\xc9\xce\xaa\xb2\xfa\xc6\xb7\xc3\xc5\xc0\xe0\xc6\xeb\xc8\xab\xa1\xa2\xb9\xa6\xc4\xdc\xc7\xbf\xb4\xf3\xa1\xa2\xb8\xb2\xb8\xc7\xd0\xd0\xd2\xb5\xb7\xb6\xce\xa7\xb9\xe3\xb7\xba\xa1\xa2\xc2\xfa\xd7\xe3\xb8\xf7\xc0\xe0\xd0\xc5\xcf\xa2\xcf\xb5\xcd\xb3\xbd\xa8\xc9\xe8\xb5\xc4GIS\xc8\xed\xbc\xfe\xc6\xb7\xc5\xc6\xa3\xac\xb2\xa2\xc9\xee\xc8\xeb\xb5\xbd\xb9\xfa\xc4\xda\xb8\xf7\xb8\xf6GIS\xd0\xd0\xd2\xb5\xd3\xa6\xd3\xc3\xa1\xa3'}
```

Comment: so the reason it doesnt work for particular websites, is the difference of that website right? not the problem of the code)

Comment: Yes. I think so.

Answer (score 3):

I would re-write to use selectors which select for `content` attribute also present and ensure case is correct for value of `name` attribute. As `keywords` can be either upper or lower case, and also `description`, you need to allow for this in your css selector or else no match will be found. You can do this with Or syntax in selector

```
keywords = [item['content'] for item in soup.select('[name=Keywords][content], [name=keywords][content]')]
descriptions = [item['content'] for item in soup.select('[name=Description][content], [name=description][content]')]
```